# sed command does not work with find -exec?

Tags: bash, sed, find, locate

I have this file:

file.txt:

```
...
threshold:
  swipe: 2
  pinch: 2 

interval:
  swipe: 2
  pinch: 2
```

No, if I do :

```
$ locate config.yml | while read i; do sed '/swipe|pinch/s/[0-9]/3/' $i; done
```

it will changed the `2` to `3`:

```
 ...
    threshold:
      swipe: 3
      pinch: 3 

    interval:
      swipe: 3
      pinch: 3
```

but this with `find` does not :

```
sudo find / -name config.yml -exec sed -n '/swipe|pinch/s/[0-9]/3/' '{}' \+
```

the regex is the same, so that is not the issue, so what is?

Comment: Why is there a `-n` in your `-exec`-run `sed`?

Comment: from `man sed`: `       -n, --quiet, --silent

              suppress automatic printing of pattern space`

Comment: Change `|` to `\|` or add option `-E`, add option `-i` if you want to edit in-place, remove `-n` and you don't need to escape `+`.

Comment: still does not work: `sudo find / -name config.yml -exec sed -En '/swipe\|pinch/s/[0-9]/3/' '{}' \+` . I will add `-i` once I would see it substitued correctly but for now, do not even substitued

Comment: Remove the `-n`, it suppresses any output. And you don't need to escape `|` if you use `-E`.

Comment: @Freddy that is not true, it  suppresses pattern space, not any ouput, It should display matched substitution. So wihout `-n` it outputs every line, but the lines are not still substitued. This is not solution

Comment: could you try it without single quotes around the curly brackets?

Comment: @Herdsman You only get output with `sed -n` if you use the `p` command or the `/p` flag with  the `s` command. Results of substitutions are not printed automatically (not with `-n` and not without `-n`). Also, you are clearly not running the commands that you show as the given command with `locate` would not replace `2` with `3` in the file that you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top you reference a file name `file.txt`, but then only deal with files of the name `config.yml`, so I assume it's `config.yml` that contains these patterns.

The `locate` and `bash` [tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) are kinda misleading, as this has nothing to do with both of those :) More importantly, what kind of environment is this? On Linux systems, [GNU/sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) is commonly installed and needs the `-E` option to [understand](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#ERE-syntax) the `swipe|pinch` condition. Bracket expressions (the `[0-9]` part of your pattern) works even without `-E`.

So, with that being considered, the following works with GNU/sed and [BSD/sed](https://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sed++NetBSD-current):

```
locate config.yml | while read -r i; do sed -E '/swipe|pinch/s/[0-9]/3/' "$i"; done
```

Or, with `find`:

```
find . -name config.yml -exec sed -E '/swipe|pinch/s/[0-9]/3/' '{}' +
```

NB: your pattern `/swipe|pinch/` was correct, the suggestion to change it to escape the pipe symbol to `/swipe\|pinch/` will not work as now it's no longer a regular expression and would match a literal `|` and thus would not match any content of your file. However, it *would* work if the surrounding apostrophes (`'`) are omitted:

```
sed -E /swipe\|pinch/s/[0-9]/3/
```

Comment: It looks like the suggestion was to escape `|` with a ``\`` _or_ to add the `-E` option. As far as I can see they both work with GNU sed (or, for what it's worth, Busybox sed; I can't test any other implementation). I.e. GNU BRE supports alternation, it just requires the `\|` syntax.

Comment: I know `find` has many option, but I rather use `locate` since it is faster, and then simpy pipe output for further proccessing (e.g. `find blabla | xargs cat` is the same as `find / -type f -name blabla -exec cat`, but `find` from root takes so long, but `locate` uses database for this purpose\